# TypeError: Cannot read properties 'toString')

Tags: hardhat

I'm trying to auto update my front-end repo with the contract address, but I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read properties 'toString'), I tried removing the toString and it prompted me to convert toString, I imported network from hardhat so im not sure what's wrong.[image]

```
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs");
async function updateContractAddress() {
    const chainId = network.config.chainId.toString();
    const nftMarketPlace = await ethers.getContract("BullChordMarket");
    const contractAddresses = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(frontEndContractsFile, "utf8")
    );
    if (chainId in contractAddresses) {
        if (
            !contractAddresses[chainId]["BullChordMarket"].includes(
                nftMarketPlace.address
            )
        ) {
            contractAddresses[chainId]["BullChordMarket"].push(
                nftMarketPlace.address
            );
        }
    } else {
        contractAddresses[chainId] = {
            BullChordMarket: [nftMarketPlace.address],
        };
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(frontEndContractsFile, JSON.stringify(contractAddresses));
}
```

Comment: Try to log the chainId in the console

Comment: It breaks before it gets to the log, so I get no output

Comment: @Santos First, are you sure the error is caused in that section of the code? In that case add more logs before the error. Try logging `network.config` or even `network`.

Answer (score 0):

The error log means that chainId is undefined.

When you run the deploy script, you can specify which network config you want to use, it usually defines inside `hardhat.config.js` (see [documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config)).
You can console log the `network` object first to see if it's correctly setup and contains correct config object and config.chainId.